# Объясните, что такое каскад Хаара

Tags: python, opencv

Я понял, что это `.xml` файл, содержащий какую то информацию. Но как он создается, и что он содержит?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html

Comment: Я вбил слова в гугл и получил ответ. Попробуй и ты.

Comment: Спасибо, я не смог открыть гугл. Я сути не понимаю, вот как на основе этого объяснить другим людям, что это такое

Comment: Я понимаю, что это какие то признаки. Но они откуда то берутся. Ничего не понимаю. Быть эникейщиком плохо, кстати

Comment: Плохо быть Романом Пугачевым, он не знает что такое каскад Хаара и не в состоянии найти информацию. А быть эникейщиком превосходно.

Answer (score 0):

> Признаки Хаара — признаки цифрового изображения, используемые в распознавании образов. Своим названием они обязаны интуитивным сходством с вейвлетами Хаара. Признаки Хаара использовались в первом детекторе лиц, работающем в реальном времени.

[wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Только в проект, к сожалению, это не поместить. Никто не знает, что это такое, я понял.

Comment: @РоманПугачев https://habr.com/ru/post/208092/